# How to fix a Soft Body on selected points in Cinema 4D?

Tags: animation, cinema4d, simulation

as the question says...  I want to fix a soft body on selected points so when the physics kicks in it should behave as natural as possible.

Progress: When i create a point selection tag end drop the object and the selection tag in a fixed connector B object field its starts good and than starts dancing and deforming into abstract art haha. What am I doing wrong?

If anyone has any ideas please share, but do mind that I'm a beginner. Thanx

[Example I made with cloth engine. But I need it to work with soft body.](http://www.mediafire.com/watch/pggcs8jb5yszq6n/betaFinale.mp4)

Comment: Dino, you should focus on one question at a time here. Probably edit out numbers 2 to 4. You can make other questions, but be mindful not to flood us with too many questions at once.

Comment: Yeah, you are right. I just felt so hyped so questions kept popping in my head and this happened. Sorry... will edit it right away.